# Problem With Struts Select Default Value

Tags: struts2

I am using a LinkedList of a very simple custom class I created to fill the select statement.  I got everything set properly (values and keys), but I can not load my default value.

This is the code I used for my select statement:

```
<s:select name="reports" list="filters" listKey="id" listValue="name" value="%{filterName}" onchange="filterResults(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text,this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)"/>
```

The filters list that is used has an id field (Integer) and a name field (String).
I know that the value in filterName should match with a value in the drop down list.  I printed it to the screen with a property tag, but nothing is selected when the page loads.  Any help is much obliged.

Comment: `%{filterName}` needs to match a value in listKey, which is `id`.

Comment: In the list attribute try too put list="filters.{filterName}"